# Extensions of $A-$modules

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

Consider the short exact sequence of $A-$modules $$0\rightarrow N\rightarrow E\rightarrow M\rightarrow 0$$
Let  $M'\subset M$ and $N'\subset N$ be two submodules.

> How  to classify extensions $$0\rightarrow N'\rightarrow E'\rightarrow M'\rightarrow 0$$  such that $E'$ is a submodule of $E$.

Answer (score 0):

As a first step, you may assume $M=M'$. Any extension of the type you desire factor through the pull back by $M'\subset M$.

Thus assuming $M=M'$, we have the natural map $\operatorname{Ext}^1(M,N')\to \operatorname{Ext}^1(M,N)$. The given extension corresponds to an element $\eta\in \operatorname{Ext}^1(M,N)$. Any element in $\operatorname{Ext}^1(M,N')$ which maps to $\eta$ ( there may be none) gives an extension of the desired type.

Comment: This map $\operatorname{Ext}^1(M,N')\to \operatorname{Ext}^1(M,N)$ is the pushout functor? But if $M'$ is different from $M$, we didn't have this functor?

Comment: I showed why you can assume $M=M'$ for your question.